# VBA, Sheet names and Headers

Tags: vba, excel

First off I have tried search and could not figure it out, I got two Macros, I need to clean this up abit.

1)  I need to get sheet names but not the active sheet I am putting the work in. Into a column under sheet names but keep in mind I will need to do this for multiple files.

My end goal is to eventually to do this for a directory of files and into. a master workbook. Extract my desired values from the directory of files and put into my master sheet to be used for pivot tables:

```
    Sub GetName()

   Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
   Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
     Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"
    Range("A2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name


    End Sub
```

also have this :

```
   Sub SheetNames()
Columns(1).Insert
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Cells(i, 3) = Sheets(i).Name
Next i
  End Sub
```

Need help combining them and getting them to work together without errors I am getting.

Comment: What is it producing as of now, and what are the errors? Does the second sub work as you intended?

Comment: So is your goal? Get all sheet names from all spreadsheets in a directory, and list them on the currently active worksheet.

Comment: And in "C1", what column name do you wish to list.  Is there only one column in each worksheet? Is it columnA and the header will be in row 1?

Comment: Hi guys, I want the headers in a newsheet/workbook. Aswell as under the headers  I want the columns to have the correct data. So file name in A1 will have the active workbooks file name, sheet name will have the sheets name in the column, column name will have a list of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to be a bit more clear as everyone has stated but here you go to get the sheet names minus the active sheet

```
Sub GetNames()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
iRow = 2
iCol = 2

Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"
Range("A2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = ws.Name
        ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol+1).Value = <someCalculatedValue>
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, works good! Just say I a macro that does a calculation and I want the results to go into col C how would I do that?

Comment: To put the data in Col. C, you'll just need to do something like `Cells(1,3).Value = 1`.  That'll put the value `1` in cell `C1`.  Thus, you can see in the code above, that Sorceri puts all the worksheet names in column `iCol`, which he set equal to `3` which is column `C`.

Comment: thanks Bruce Wayne, so add `Cells(1,3).Value = 11` to my macro?

Comment: @BruceWayne uptick for the catch I set the wrong column for the sheets.   Fixed now so it goes to B as well as added how to add the calculated value to the next column over IE: C

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but something like this is a good start.

```
Sub GetNames()

    'Headers
    Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
    Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
    Range("C1").Value = "Column Name"

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Liss, thanks works good. I'd probably need some explanation on how to continue this and modify. Ex: How to add to column C.

Comment: What do you want to populate in column C?  Are you looking at a set number of column names?

Comment: I have a macro that does Advanced.Filter on the 3 excel sheets in the file. It spits out the results on a new sheet. I would like these results to show under the Set of column names. So: A is file name, B is sheet name(consists of 3 sheets) and then C will have the unique values for each of those 3 sheets. ([img]http://i.imgur.com/HypWjXr.jpg[/img])

Comment: Hey @Liss, would you know how to exclude the active worksheet name from this?

Comment: You can add an if to check against the ActiveSheet name, but then you'll leave an extra as it goes through the loop.  
`If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then`
For adding the column names it depends on how it looks on the actual sheet you're getting the data from.